# "Points" not available for .C() for package "dprep"

Tags: r, feature-selection, discretization

I want to perform discretization in order to perform mutual information based feature selection for supervised learning R.

```
library(dprep)
data(iris)
iris.discme=disc.mentr(my.iris,1:5)
```

I am getting following error:

> Error in .C("Points", as.double(x), as.integer(n), mpoint = double(n),
>   :   "Points" not available for .C() for package "dprep"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `dprep` was removed from CRAN. Last update was 6 years ago.

Comment: But I wanted to compile and use on ubuntu.

Comment: On which version of R?

Comment: "R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18)"

Comment: It is likely to not work, due to major changes in R for last 6 years.

Comment: OK! Do you have any idea about any other package for Mutual Information based Feature selection for supervised learning.

Comment: No, any idea. Give a try to `install.packages('sos'); library(sos); findFn("Mutual Information based Feature selection")`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81595/discussion-between-kravi-and-pascal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the library "dprep". The error is telling you that there is *no* C function called "Points", even though disc.mentr() attempted to call this function. I would notify the authors of dprep.

I just looked on CRAN and did not see a library called "dprep". If it was available earlier, that may be a sign that it has been taken down.

Comment: Yeah It was removed, tut I wanted to compile and use on ubuntu.